# subset slow in large matrix

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I have a numeric vector of length 5,000,000

```
>head(coordvec)
[1] 47286545 47286546 47286547 47286548 47286549 472865
```

and a 3 x 1,400,000 numeric matrix

```
>head(subscores)
        V1       V2     V3
1 47286730 47286725  0.830
2 47286740 47286791  0.065
3 47286750 47286806 -0.165
4 47288371 47288427  0.760
5 47288841 47288890  0.285
6 47288896 47288945  0.225
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that for each number in coordvec, find the average of V3 for rows in subscores in which V1 and V2 encompass the number in coordvec. To do that, I am taking the following approach:

```
results<-numeric(length(coordvec))
for(i in 1:length(coordvec)){
    select_rows <- subscores[, 1] < coordvec[i] & subscores[, 2] > coordvec[i]
scores_subset <- subscores[select_rows, 3]
results[m]<-mean(scores_subset)
}
```

This is very slow, and would take a few days to finish. Is there a faster way?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are two challenging parts to this question. The first is finding the overlaps. I'd use the `IRanges` package from [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.11/bioc/html/IRanges.html) (`?findInterval` in the base package might also be useful)

```
library(IRanges)
```

creating width 1 ranges representing the coordinate vector, and set of ranges representing the scores; I sort the coordinate vectors for convenience, assuming that duplicate coordinates can be treated the same

```
coord <- sort(sample(.Machine$integer.max, 5000000))
starts <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1200000)
scores <- runif(length(starts))

q <- IRanges(coord, width=1)
s <- IRanges(starts, starts + 100L)
```

Here we find which `query` overlaps which `subject`

```
system.time({
    olaps <- findOverlaps(q, s)
})
```

This takes about 7s on my laptop. There are different types of overlaps (see `?findOverlaps`) so maybe this step requires a bit of refinement.
The result is a pair of vectors indexing the query and overlapping subject.

```
> olaps
Hits of length 281909
queryLength: 5000000
subjectLength: 1200000
       queryHits subjectHits 
        <integer>   <integer> 
 1             19      685913 
 2             35      929424 
 3             46     1130191 
 4             52       37417
```

I think this is the end of the first complicated part, finding the 281909 overlaps. (I don't think the data.table answer offered elsewhere addresses this, though I could be mistaken...)

The next challenging part is calculating a large number of means. The built-in way would be something like

```
olaps0 <- head(olaps, 10000)
system.time({
    res0 <- tapply(scores[subjectHits(olaps0)], queryHits(olaps0), mean)
})
```

which takes about 3.25s on my computer and appears to scale linearly, so maybe 90s for the 280k overlaps. But I think we can accomplish this tabulation efficiently with `data.table`. The original coordinates are `start(v)[queryHits(olaps)]`, so as

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(coord=start(q)[queryHits(olaps)],
                 score=scores[subjectHits(olaps)])
res1 <- dt[,mean(score), by=coord]$V1
```

which takes about 2.5s for all 280k overlaps.

Some more speed can be had by recognizing that the query hits are ordered. We want to calculate a mean for each run of query hits. We start by creating a variable to indicate the ends of each query hit run

```
idx <- c(queryHits(olaps)[-1] != queryHits(olaps)[-length(olaps)], TRUE)
```

and then calculate the cumulative scores at the ends of each run, the length of each run, and the difference between the cumulative score at the end and at the start of the run

```
scoreHits <- cumsum(scores[subjectHits(olaps)])[idx]
n <- diff(c(0L, seq_along(idx)[idx]))
xt <- diff(c(0L, scoreHits))
```

And finally, the mean is

```
res2 <- xt / n
```

This takes about 0.6s for all the data, and is identical to (though more cryptic than?) the data.table result

```
> identical(res1, res2)
[1] TRUE
```

The original coordinates corresponding to the means are

```
start(q)[ queryHits(olaps)[idx] ]
```

Comment: thanks. scoreHits is giving me a vector of shorter length than olaps. how can I relate res2 to the coordinates the averages are associated with?

Comment: The original coordinates are `start(q)[queryHits(olaps)][idx]`; I've modified the question to incorporate this (a little more efficiently) in both the data.table and more complicated example.

Comment: Hi Martin. Agreed, the overlapping ranges is challenging, I can't think of a nicer way than yours. You might find a keyed by is faster than that unkeyed by. The `setkey` first will have cost of course but if you know for sure that the data is already sorted (as here iiuc) then you can `setattr(DT,"sorted",keycols)` instead with no cost.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be faster :

```
require(data.table)
subscores <- as.data.table(subscores)

subscores[, cond := V1 < coordvec & V2 > coordvec]
subscores[list(cond)[[1]], mean(V3)]
```

`list(cond)[[1]]` because: "When i is a single variable name, it is not considered an expression of column names and is instead evaluated in calling scope." source: `?data.table`

Comment: Can you provide a little simulated data to show how this works? I don't think creating `cond` works when `coordvec` is not a scalar?

Comment: You're right--i misread the structure proposed in the question. This will require a more complicated algorithm. I'll post it if I figure it out.

Comment: @Michael Slightly easier `i` to get around that is `subscores[cond==TRUE, mean(V3)]` or `subscores[(cond), mean(V3)]`.

Comment: Michael, I'm sure I've done something like these overlapping groups before but haven't found it yet. A `roll` join on starts, a roll on ends, then vecseq between perhaps. Or make `coorddev` a key only `data.table` and join the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Since your answer isn't easily reproducible and even if it were, none of your `subscores` meet your boolean condition, I'm not sure if this does exactly what you're looking for but you can use one of the `apply` family and a function.

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  y <- subscores[, 1] < x & subscores[, 2] > x
  mean(subscores[y, 3])
}

sapply(coordvec, myfun)
```

You can also take a look at `mclapply`.  If you have enough memory this will probably speed things up significantly. However, you could also look at the `foreach` package with similar results.  You've got your `for loop` "correct" by assigning into `results` rather than growing it, but really, you're doing a **lot** of comparisons.  It will be hard to speed this up much.